# how to undo 'Alias' in Virtualhost

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, alias, apache2

I wanted `www.domain1.tld/domain2` to point to `/www/directory2`

So I added an 'Alias line' to my Virtualhost config `apache2/sites-available/domain1.conf` like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerName www.domain1.tld
    DocumentRoot /www/directory1

    Alias /domain2 /www/directory2    #Alias line
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I've removed that 'Alias line' and added a new Virtualhost config `apache2/sites-available/domain2.conf` where `www.domain2.tld` points to `/www/directory2`.

However, when I visit `www.domain2.tld` via a browser, the URL changes to `www.domain1.tld/domain2` and I get a page saying "Not Found, The requested URL /domain2 was not found on this server"

How do I undo whatever the 'Alias line' did? It seems to have permanently modified some hosts - type file in my server.

(In case it matters, all this was in the service of a PrestaShop installation.)

Comment: `Alias` doesn't generate a redirect, so something else is doing that.  What relevant configuration portion have you not shared with us?

Comment: Could the PrestaShop installation have created some redirects? Can you suggest some files I can check to check for redirects?

Comment: Anything's possible.  If Presta's doing it, it could be in a .htaccess file, or it could be in the Presta codebase.  However, it's never going to have figured out to issue the redirect all by itself, so *something* you did caused this to happen.